# Falla al interaccionar userforms de excel con python a traves de Flask y Xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, flask

Estoy intentando relacionar 2 userforms. El primero tienen un navegador que muestra una página hecha con flask y Python y se relaciona con Excel a través de xlwings, el segundo un tiene un refedit y un botón para confirmar. La idea es que al apretar un botón en el navegador del primer userform, este se cierra/minimice y se abra el otro userform que muestra el refedit para seleccionar una celda y que luego de confirmar con el botón este se cierre/minimice y se vuelva a abrir el primer userform con el navegador. El problema es que al intentar abrir el primer userform luego de cerrar el segundo con el refedit la página queda cargando, el servidor queda trabado hasta que cierro el userform con el navegador y recién ahí puede continuar procesando. Luego de muchas pruebas di conque la línea que falla en el código de python del primer navegador es la que usa xlwings, línea que en la primera vuelta no falla. Logre armar un código mínimo que recrea el error (a veces ocurre y a veces carga bien sin un patrón claro).
Claramente existe un conflicto en como estoy pensando la relación entre los userform pero no logre descifrar donde está la falla. Otro tema importante es que luego de la falla del navegador que no carga, si lo cierro no logro recuperar el foco en el excel. Solo después de apretar alt F4 y cancelar logro recuperar el control del excel.

Logre un código mínimo que recrea el error:

**Vistas en Python:**

```
@ap.route("/test1", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test1():
    print('enter test1')
    wb = xw.Book(path)
    print('pass wb')
    return render_template('test.html.j2')

@ap.route("/test2", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def test2():
    print('enter test2')
    wb = xw.Book(path)
    print(xw.books)
    your_macro = wb.macro('pruu2')
    your_macro()
    return '', 204
```

**Userform con navegador(llamado WebBrowser1):**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://127.0.0.1:5000/test1"
End Sub
```

**Userform con Refedit y boton confirmar. Codigo para confirmación del boton:**

```
Private Sub Conf_Click()
    Dim valor As String
    valor = RefEdit5.Value
    Unload test2
    test1.Show
    
End Sub
```

**Modulo necesarios (asociar showtest1 a un boton para comenzar):**

```
Sub pruu2()
    MsgBox "open userform refedit"
    Unload test1
    test2.Show
End Sub

Sub showtest1()
    test1.Show
End Sub
```

No tengo mucha experiencia en VBA y supongo que el problema es como pretendo relacionarlo pero no encontré hasta ahora ninguna forma de hacer que funcione. Y como mencione antes, a veces funciona y a veces falla.
Alguna idea de cual seria la forma correcta de lograr lo que intento?

Comment: Estas intentando inyectar contenido desde el navegador a la aplicación excel mediante un servidor web, o entiendo mal?

Comment: Si, en el código de prueba no lo hago, pero en el original si. Uso el paquete xlwings que me permite conectar python con excel, y me permite a traves de un servidor web hecho con Flask leer e instertar en el excel. En la primera vuelta funciona bien, pero luego del userform de refedit el servidor se cuelga cuando intenta conectar a traves de xlwings. Igual mi sospecha es que el problema va por el lado de VBA pero no pude resolverlo

Comment: Yo imagino que puede ser un problema de coherencia, no veo que el servidor tengas ningún tipo de `esta pasando esto` y habrán acciones que se salta y se pone a esperarlas; aparte de eso, si solo es para añadir funcionalidad puedes gasta la [api de C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-visual-c)